# How to login multiple different auth0 users with jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

**What I am trying to do:** 
I want to simulate 100 different users (username+password combinations) into the same site (that uses an integrated Auth0 login), and each user clicks a button.

**What I tried:** 
Using other questions from stackoverflow, I created:
- a login.txt file:
[image]

- and a "CSV data set config":
  [image]
- and a "body data" on the login page, where I tried to take the USER and PASS from the text file:
  [image]

**The problem:**
- when I check the Request in the result tree, I can only see the correct username being taken from the login.txt file, but the password field is just ${PASS} and not an actual password:
[image]

**Questions:**

1. What am I doing wrong, as the password is not loaded from the file?
2. I have a lot of errors in the result tree, and I think it's because of the Auth0... do you have any guidelines on using it with JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You variable name you define is PASSWORD and not PASS,

You can call it in your test `${PASSWORD}` instead of `${PASS}`

Or, in the [guideline](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#user_variables) it states to use ${PASS} so you can change in CSV Data Set Config the Variable Names to `USER,PASS`